# Always include file when importing module in python

Tags: python, module

How can I have a file that is always imported when then module is imported?

*eg*: consider this module.

```
/ myMod
   / __init__.py
   / important.py               # defines myFunc
   / extraFunctions.py
   / classDefinitions.py
```

All of the functions that anyone using module would be in *important.py*. I want *important.py* to be included by default in myMod.  So using the module would be like this.

```
import myMod
myMod.myFunc()
```

instead of

```
from myModimport important
important.myMod()
```

or

```
import myMod
myMod.important.myFunc()
```

Should `important.py` be renamed to `__init__.py`, `main.py` or `__main__.py` or can `__init__.py` be edited to include `important.py` as default or even just select functions from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Raydel's answer, I would like to add this point: if your `important` module contains private functions you don't want to export out, there is a way to control that. Here is an example:

```
# important.py

# This magic variable controls what gets import via
# from important import *
__all__ = ['dothis', 'dothat']

def dothis():
    pass

def dothat():
    pass

def private1():
    pass
```

Using the magic variable `__all__`, you can control which function gets export.

## Update

From `__init__.py`, you can do:

```
from important import dothis, dothat
```

This is another way to control which entity (function, variable) get imported.

However, if from `__init__.py`, you can do this:

```
import important
important.private1() # OK
```

or:

```
from important import private1 # OK, too
```

That means you can override the `__all__` magic variable if you want to. In my opinion, the former method is better since it does not make `private1` available to those who import `myMod`.

Comment: You're right! This is important. I forgot that. +1.

Comment: Could I alternatively do `from important import dothis, dothat` in `__init__.py`?  So if another module file imports important.py that file can access those private functions?  Or does `__all__` only effect `from x import *` and not `import x`?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to rename `important.py` to `__init__.py` you just have to add to your `__init__.py` file:

```
from important import *
```

that's all.